# How to check the disk space of remote server through command prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have been running the following script in the cmd file to get the free disk space of remote servers.It returns size in byte, is there any way to get the size in MB or GB, ideally percentage would be good.

```
echo off

echo .
echo SERVER-1:
wmic /NODE:"SERVER-1" logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption
echo .

echo .
echo .
echo SERVER-2:
wmic /NODE:"TSERVER-2" logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption
echo .
pause
```

Comment: Which Windows version?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend PowerShell rather than `wmic` in `cmd.exe`. Short example:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName server-1,server-2 -Filter "DriveType=3" | Select-Object `
  @{Name = "ComputerName"; Expression = {$_.__SERVER}},
  DeviceID,
  @{Name = "Size"; Expression = {$_.Size / 1GB}},
  @{Name = "Free"; Expression = {$_.FreeSpace / 1GB}}
```

This produces output such as the following:

```
ComputerName  DeviceID             Size             Free
------------  --------             ----             ----
server-1      C:       99.5097618103027 64.3940238952637
server-1      D:       199.873043060303 183.510925292969
server-2      C:       99.5097618103027 64.3940238952637
server-2      D:       199.873043060303 183.510925292969
```